# How to change position of an image in a TextView to the left-bottom-side?

Tags: java, android, xml

There's a linear layout given with a TextView, which contains an image. I want to position the image on the left-bottom side of the TextView.

I did this with android:drawable:Left

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/xmpp_chatlist_tv_partnerID_inc_Message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80sp"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
        android:layout_weight="0.125"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/xmpp_notation"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="left">
    </TextView>
```

I also did this:

```
  textView_partnerID_inc.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            R.drawable.xmpp_notation, 0, 0, 0);
```

How to get the image shown on the left-bottom side?

Comment: you have to use RelativeLayout inside this you can have textview and imageview placed seperately.

Comment: You can resolve it using a custom textview as I posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/73364388/7540530.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can use `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text aligned bottom left"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/apk_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can use a `RelativeLayout` like so:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text aligned bottom left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/apk_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or using a `Drawable`, you can do this by adding `gravity` top:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xmpp_chatlist_tv_partnerID_inc_Message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80sp"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    android:layout_weight="0.125"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/xmpp_notation"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="left|top">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text aligned bottom left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

than add the image