# How to set drawable in Top-Left in a textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_small_6"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password_hint"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_edit"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_14"/>
```

This is my textview. I want to set the drawable on left of this textview. But the problem is, If the text is multiline, then drawable appears center-vertical in the text view.

Is there any option to set drawable on Top-Left of the textview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Custom drawable class by extending a drawable class and use for drawable .eg:

```
public class TopLeftGravityDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
   private final Drawable mDrawable;

   public TopLeftGravityDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
       mDrawable = drawable;
   }

   @Override
   public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
       return mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
   }

   @Override
   public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
       return mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
       int halfCanvas= canvas.getHeight() / 2;
       int halfDrawable = mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;

       // align to top
       canvas.save();
       canvas.translate(0, -halfCanvas + halfDrawable);
       mDrawable.draw(canvas);
       canvas.restore();
   }
}
```

Usage :

```
       Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_customer);

       TopGravityDrawable gravityDrawable = new TopGravityDrawable(drawable);

       drawable.setBounds(0, 6, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
       gravityDrawable.setBounds(0, 6, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
       textview.setCompoundDrawables(gravityDrawable, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @Avinash Kumar Singh solution. If you have a small image it will be higher than a first line of text.

[image]

In this case you should center the image by the first line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/dot"
        tool:drawableStart="@drawable/dot" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tool:text="This is my textview. I want to set the drawable on left of this textview" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> **No, their is no any direct option to set drawable on Top-Left of the textview.**

But you can create some custom design to achieve this. Replace your `TextView` with the below code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="@string/forgot_password_hint"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_14"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I thought of this one, but this approach requires a lot of handling of visibility.

Answer (score 1):

This has solved my issue:

```
class MyTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
    ) : AppCompatTextView(context, style) {
        private val leftDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.checkmark)
    
        override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
            super.onDraw(canvas)
            setBulletPoint(compoundDrawables[0], canvas)
        }
    
    private fun setBulletPoint(drawableLeft: Drawable?, canvas: Canvas?) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            leftDrawable?.let { drlft ->
                if (lineCount == 1) {
                    setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drlft, null, null, null)
                } else {
                    val buttonWidth = drlft.intrinsicWidth
                    val buttonHeight = drlft.intrinsicHeight
                    val topSpace = abs(buttonHeight - lineHeight) / 2
           
                    drlft.setBounds(0, topSpace, buttonWidth, topSpace + buttonHeight)
                    canvas?.apply {
                        save()
                        drlft.draw(canvas)
                        restore()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep the drawable padding you should modify your code with
       canvas.apply {
                save()
                it.draw(canvas)
                setPadding(buttonWidth + compoundDrawablePadding, 0, 0, 0)
                restore()
            }
anyway it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If a programmatic approach is suitable, You could extend Drawable in such way that it occupies the full height available and draws on top.

If You want an solution using only interface builder, You should just wrap the TextView in a horizontal LinearLayout, add an ImageView and set ImageViews gravity to be TOP.

Comment: I am trying for a programmatic approach only. Android does not provide any XML methods to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in xml file

change   android:drawableStart   to android:drawableLeft

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_small_6"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password_hint"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_edit"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium_14"/>
```

Comment: This is not working in case of multi line text. Drawable is always shown 'Center vertical' of the textview.

Answer (score -1):

use  `android:paddingBottom="10dp"`

Comment: adding padding from the bottom will add padding to text too.